# View controller won't push

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a function inside my app delegate which is supposed to push a View Controller when called from a Siri Shortcut.

```
func pushNewView() {
    if let wind = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window {
        if let rootViewController = wind?.rootViewController {
            let viewToPush = TripTableViewController()
            if let alreadySomeOneThere = rootViewController.presentedViewController {
                alreadySomeOneThere.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewToPush, animated: true)
            } else {
                rootViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewToPush, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I called `pushNewView()` from my AppDelegate, nothing happens.

If I present the view controller instead of pushing it, that does work but I want the view controller pushed.

I'm not using any storyboards, all my code is programmatic.

Does anyone know how to make this function successfully push the View Controller?

Comment: as your description 'rootViewController' don't have 'UINavigationController' as container, so embed rootViewController to navigationController.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is happening because neither `alreadySomeOneThere` nor `rootViewController` are embedded in a navigation controller.

In order to push another view controller, there needs to be an existing navigation controller in place.

You need to do one of two things. Either redo your setup such that `alreadySomeOneThere` and `rootViewController` are embedded in a navigation controller, or you need to present the new view controller from `alreadySomeOneThere` or `rootViewController`.

Please note that you can't push a navigation controller. If you choose to put `alreadySomeOneThere` and `rootViewController` in a navigation controller, then just push `viewToPush`. Don't create another navigation controller.

If you instead decide to present the new view controller from `alreadySomeOneThere` or `rootViewController`, then depending on the needs of `viewToPush`, you may or may not need `viewToPush` embedded its own navigation controller.

Comment: So the active viewcontroller is in a navigation controller and I made it so `viewToPush` isn't in a nvigation controller, still nothing happens. I've updated my code.

Comment: For some reason, my rootViewController's navigation controller is equal to nil even though I embeded it in applicationDidFinishLaunching